# How to configure Azure DevOps CI-CD pipelines for ASP.NET Core with Angular?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have created the CI Pipeline for ASP.NET Core with Angular and the CI process worked without any issues. But after the deployment it always shows this error:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> Request ID: 0HLNE88S5VTHH:00000003 Development Mode
>
> Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information
>   about the error that occurred.
>
> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed
>   applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from
>   exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development
>   environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable
>   to Development and restarting the app.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline...?

Comment: What's the value of your "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable? In your appsettings.json file, do you specified the key which generated in azure or some other database service to "ConnectionStrings"?

Comment: appsettings.json:{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    } },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "commands": {
    "Development": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development",
    "Preview": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Preview",
    "Production": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production"
  },

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk

which one do you need CI or CD??

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress

Answer (score 1):

This may caused by you did not specified the [ConnectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings) in your appsettings.json file.

You'd need to add the key which generated in azure or any other database service to the argument:`ConnectionString`.

Try with add below script to your `appsettings.json` file:

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "{key}"
    },
```